# A question on permutation and multiplication

Tags: permutations, combinations

I will illustrate my question via simple examples.

**Ex-1** The number of ways of filling 2 chairs by 4 persons is $P(4, 2) = 4 \times 3$.

The fact is “to find the number of permutations, we need to use multiplications”. I am thinking about the reverse---“a multiplication will induce a permutation”. Let consider another example.

**Ex-2** The number of ways of getting 2 pairs from a hand of 4 cards is $\dfrac {C(13,1)C(4, 2) \times C(12, 1)C(4, 2)}{2!}$.

In the example, there is a multiplication and hence it induces a permutation. That is why a division of (2!) is necessary to get the needed combination of two pairs.

**Ex-3** The number of ways of getting 2 pairs from a poker hand is $[\dfrac {C(13, 1)C(4, 2)C(12, 1)C(4, 2)}{2!}] \times [44]$.

Again, there is a multiplication between the two squared brackets but why handling the permutation is not necessary?

Comment: The division by $2!$ is needed because there are $2$ subsets of the same size while order is not supposed to matter, but will matter if you step by step pick the pairs as if they were a permutation of pairs. There's only one subset of size $1$ being picked, so there's no need to "unorder" them (it). Count how many full houses there are for another example where you don't need to unorder them (or .... you can imagine dividing by $1!$ if you want a uniform formula pattern)

Comment: @Ned I have thought of dividing by 1! too. I try to convince myself in the following way. After the selections, we have 2 objects to permute. One is the chosen 2 pairs and the other is the chosen extra card for the 5th. If that is the case, we get a $1 \times 1 = 1$ permutation; and 1-permuatation is the same as 1-combination. But it seems that this thinking contradicts the 4 card example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by contradicting the 4 card example, but generally I wouldn't put too much emphasis on the words permutation and combination. They don't always capture everything that is happening precisely and simply as they do in very elementary examples. Look at other similar examples (like full house in 5 cards, 3 of a kind in 5 cards, (2,2,1,1) [i.e. 2 pairs] in 6 cards) and try to understand them, even if you can't reduce the insight to the words permutations and combinations.

Comment: @Ned Pls ignore the contradiction part because there is no such thing and it is just my "over-worry".